# Deploying to our test server from a dev machine doesn't work

Tags: biztalk

We have 2 dev machines (dev1 and dev2) and we are trying to change the way we deploy. Until now we used to deploy to the local biztalk admin console, then create an MSI and instal that to the live server.

Now, we want to directly deploy to a test server (bztest-03) and once testing is done, create an msi on that machine. This works for the dev2 mavhine, but the dev1 machine gives the below error. the machine gives this error even when the same user as on dev2 is logged on and the rights on the database look the same (and on user roles)

What could cause these errors? The analytics_PortTrackingInfo isn't something we made and i find little hits on google about it and biztalk.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Deployment cannot initialize the connection to the database
>   "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "BZTEST-03\DTA". Verify that you have the
>   required security permissions and that communication between
>   Distributed Transaction Coordinator services on the machines involved
>   is not prevented by current DTC security,   firewall or authentication
>   settings. Invalid object name 'analytics_PortTrackingInfo'.           0

Answer (score 3):

That error notwithstanding, you can't Deploy to a remote machine from Visual Studio.  That has always been the case.

If you're looking to improve your Deploy process, the 'correct' way would be to add BTDF to your Solutions.

[Deployment Framework for BizTalk](https://github.com/BTDF/DeploymentFramework)

Comment: I might not be using remote machine right? My own dev machine can deploy to our test server without problems. at the deployment tab of project settings i just enter the other machines DTA database under server and i can deploy to the other server.  No Errors and the resources just come avaible on the server. My Colleauge gets the above error when deploying from visual studio though. We are using Biztalk 2013 though, if that is relevant?

Comment: i meant biztalk 2016.

Comment: @Andy It doesn't work that way.  VS can only deploy locally because Assemblies have to be GAC'd.  The correct way to improve your deployment process is to build the deployment package on a dev or build machine, then install on test.  This is exactly what BTDF is for.